# vb.net ms comm getting exception

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, serial-communication, mscomm32, mscomct2.ocx

I used microsoft com control 6.0 in the application for sending data to the led control

```
         MSComm1.EOFEnable = True
        MSComm1.SThreshold = 100
        MSComm1.InputLen = 0
        MSComm1.RThreshold = 1
        MSComm1.InBufferCount = 0
        MSComm1.OutBufferCount = 0
        MSComm1.NullDiscard = False
        MSComm1.CommPort =1
        MSComm1.PortOpen = True <-Getting exception to this line
        ......
```

I am geting Exception from **HRESULT: 0x800A1F45**  .Why does this port is not opening .
When i run it through vb6 i doesnt get error ...Anybody can help me...

Comment: Why use that old thing in a .NET application? Why not work directly with the COM port using the .NET API?

Comment: @JohnSaunders would you please suggest better .NET API for communication with COM port

Comment: See [SerialPort class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx). And don't _ever_ use any VB6 stuff with .NET. It's all over a decade old!

Answer (score 1):

Error 800A1F45 usually means the port is in use by another application.

You can decode an HRESULT according to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT).  For `0x800A1F45`, you'll find:

- The third bit is 0, so it's a Microsoft error
- The facility bits are hex 0xA, or decimal 10, which according to the [MSDN list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198%28PROT.10%29.aspx) means "Control"
- The error code bits are hex 0x01F45, or decimal 8005.  According to the [error list for the MSComm control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259389%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) that means "Port already open"

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving suggestion